# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qrcode' python 3.9

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.9

I have already installed `qrcode` library in my command prompt and also updated my command prompt. In the command prompt it says that everything is fine but when I go to PyCharm and type in:

```
import qrcode

img = qrcode.make("This is the qrcode")
img.save("myqrcode.png")
```

And when I run it, it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Antho\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import qrcode
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qrcode'
```

Comment: How did you install qrcode? What command did you use?

Comment: I used the command: pip install qrcode
I used it in my command promt and when i type pip list in command i see qrcode   6.1 if thats of any help.

Comment: Try `pip3 install qrcode`.

Comment: Do you use a virtual environment?

Comment: It still says that everything is satisfied in my command prompt but when i go to pycharm to run my code there it still couldn't fint a module named qrcode

Comment: Does typing `python3` in terminal and then typing `import qrcode` work?

Comment: If i do python3 import qrcode it says:python3: can't open file 'C:\Users\Antho\import': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. 
I don't use virtual environment

Comment: Type `python3`, THEN type `import qrcode`.

Comment: In pycharm you have to specify which python+pip interpreter to use for the project https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Comment: When i first type in `python3` and press enter and then `import qrcode` it stays blank

Comment: @Pietro i've done that but it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Xotiic you should also see which path your `python3` points to. This is purely a python environment setting. You have not shared a screenshot of PyCharm showing the environment settings in the lower right.

Comment: Also, you should add the pycharm keyword. We are fairly sure it's not a pip or python issue.

Comment: I bet you installed qrcode on virtual env and tried it on original one.

Comment: @Debendra how can I that

Comment: activate your virtual env then try.

Answer (score 5):

Install the qrcode with admin rights

```
sudo pip install qrcode
```

or

```
sudo pip3 install qrcode
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When using Windows Debian, I found that I needed to restart the app for the install to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

use `pip install qrcode` this will install the required dependency.

Answer (score 0):

For those (using Pycharm) having problem with "import qrcode" "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qrcode'".
After "pip install qrcode" at command prompt, you also need to install "package" name qrcode in Pycharm too.
File -> Settings -> Project:#### -> Python Interpreter -> "+" -> search "qrcode" -> Press "Install Package"

Answer (score 0):

run with `python` command only

```
python filename.py
```

Comment: I don't think this would necessarily solve the issue posed by the questioner, if you add a little more information around how/why this answer does solve their issue, it might be more useful.